# Crate amp footswitch question

Tags: amplifiers, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I recently bought a Crate G130C XL used, but it did not come with a footswitch. I tried looking at the manual, but it’s only 5 pages and did not seem to specify which type I need. From what I can gather, I think I need a two-button footswitch where one button switches the channels back and forth and the other switches the reverb on/off. Also, I guess I can get a pedal for the chorus switch? Any help or links would be appreciated as I don’t want to buy the wrong ones or damage the amp.

Comment: Being aware of what sockets are in the amp. is a good start. Speaking to Crate themselves is another.

Comment: I would imagine that the amp manufacturer would supply the footswich themselves. I would also recommend editing "pedal" to "footswitch". It's a more common term for the amp's footswitches (as opposed to separate effects pedal like compressor, overdrive...)

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves me correctly, the footswitch for channel switching on this amp is a temporary contact switch as opposed to the more common single pole/ double throw footswitch used in other amplifiers. The channel switching in this amp is actually done by transistor circuitry inside the amp and is activated by an temporary change in the circuits relationship to the amplifiers ground caused by stepping on the footswitch.

Comment: Contacting Crate was my first thought but all I’m finding through my searches are “out of business” articles and no customer service numbers. Thanks for trying to help me. I’m sorry, I’m only medium electronic saavy. I don’t really know what those things means but I was kind of looking for a link to a pedal that would likely work. For instance, do you know if this one would work? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000VXKUL0?ref_=pe_623860_70668670_dpLink

Comment: @Billy Campos- I looked at your link and as best I could tell it's not what you're looking for. I'm working off memory here, but what I remember about the design of this amp is that the switching is accomplished by causing the control voltage of the switching circuit to go to ground. An easy way to check if I'm correct, would be to plug a regular guitar chord into the footswitch jack on the amp with the amp switched on. Then make contact between the phone jack tip and sleeve on the phone jack at the other end of the cable. Doing this should cause the amp to switch channels.

Comment: You may need to talk to an electronic supply house to buy the footswitch and mount it in an old footswitch box if you're handy that way.  Another idea is to do a search for momentary contact footswitches. I hope this helps.

Comment: I guess I got lucky, but I found the original channel switch pedal for the amp on eBay for only $10 and bought it. Thanks for the help!